# Which function word to use when using multiple verbs

Tags: grammar, functions

Using the verbs in separate sentences:

`I upload images to the website.`

`I download images from the website.`

(I'm referring to `to` and `from` as the function words).

Which function word do I use when using the two different kinds of verbs together?

`I upload and download images <which function word here?> the website.`

Or should I not be combining them, and instead separate them with an `and`?

`I upload images to the website and download images from the website.`

That's correct, but too wordy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about prepositions, and you can't use a single one if it doesn't apply to both verbs.

In the example sentence, using a conjunction is correct, but the following is the most succinct way of phrasing it:

> I *upload and download* images *to and from* the website.

In such a construction, a parallel structure is maintained.

---

Another option is to rephrase it to use a different verb and preposition, as well as a set of nouns:

> I *transfer* images *between* the website and my computer.